# Meaning of node size in force layout and calculating radius

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

What is the node size parameter in a D3.js force-layout?

Is it the pixel area on the screen, the radius or something completely different?

Lastly, how do I calculate the radius from that size value?

**Edit:** I've been confused about a D3 example, which had a `size` variable for the `nodes` objects and I thought that this variable was used in the force-layout similar to the `source` and `target` parameters. That is not the case. Consequently, this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is in screen coordinates, i.e. pixels. Note that this is not a hard limit, i.e. nodes may move outside of this area. I assume that by "radius" you mean the radius of the node circles -- the simple answer is that the two are completely unrelated.

Comment: So the size is simply a value for the hidden force node object and unrelated to the circle? That makes sense somehow. However, I guess you would often would the circle and the node object to have the same size. How do I ensure that the radius of the circle is the same as the radius of the force node object? Do I simply set them to the same value?

Comment: What do you mean by "force node object"?

Comment: I think that I'm confusing myself more. Could you elaborate a bit on what effect changing the size parameter has on each node? Perhaps I'll understand it then.

Comment: It has no effect on the individual nodes whatsoever.